Load custom ttf in cairo or pangocairo
Using the C cairo api or the pangocairo api how can I load a custom ttf font file?
How do I select the font for use when rendering some text?
and.. Can I load the font from RAM rather than a file path?

The trick is to use fontconfig.
Then to create a new font config containing a path to fonts you want.
This font config is for this application only. Later cairo/pangocairo will search for the fonts here.
#include <fontconfig/fontconfig.h>

int set_application_fonts() {
    // force empty font config with only liberation sans
    FcConfig *fc = FcConfigCreate();
    if (!fc)
        return -1;

    if (!FcConfigSetCurrent(fc))
        return -1;

    if (!FcConfigAppFontAddDir(fc, (uint8_t *)"./LiberationSans"))
        return -1;
    // NOTE: fc is leaked
    return 0;
}

remember to compile/link with the appropriate flags
pkg-config --cflags --libs fontconfig

Sadly it is not possible to give the font file contents as a blob from memory. So you must ensure that the path contains the font files. This means that if relative paths are used, the app is sensitive to the CWD from which it is executed >:(

a pangocairo snippet:
void text(cairo_t *cr, int x, int y, int w, int h, const char *txt, int size) {
    cairo_save(cr);

    cairo_set_source_rgba(1,0,0,1);

    PangoLayout *layout;
    PangoFontDescription *desc;
    layout = pango_cairo_create_layout(cr);
    pango_layout_set_text(layout, txt, -1);
    pango_layout_set_alignment(layout, PANGO_ALIGN_CENTER);
    desc = pango_font_description_from_string("Liberation Sans");
    pango_font_description_set_absolute_size(desc, size * PANGO_SCALE);

    pango_layout_set_font_description(layout, desc);
    pango_font_description_free(desc);

    int width;
    int height;
    pango_layout_get_size (layout, &width, &height);
    width /= PANGO_SCALE;
    height /= PANGO_SCALE;

    float offx = x+(w-width)/2.0f;
    float offy = y+h-(h-height)/2.0f;


    cairo_translate(cr, offx, offy);
    cairo_move_to(cr, 0, -height);
    pango_cairo_show_layout (cr, layout);

    g_object_unref (layout);

    cairo_restore(cr);
}

